# bootstrap popover on input remove title

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-popover, bootstrapvalidator

I'm using bootstrap with bootstrap validator. I add error inside popover but when I add title to the input it appear in popover.

I need popover without title but I want to add titles to inputs.

```
<input title="Your name" 
       placeholder="Name" 
       data-toggle="popover" 
       class="form-control" 
       type="text" required>
```

full code on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17255/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titles always appear in the bootstrap popovers due to the `.popover-title`  class. In order to remove it you need to do this:

```
.popover-title { display: none; }
```

BUT this will hide all titles in all popovers throughout the webpage. 
If you want to remove it from certain input elements then you can do something like this:

`#your-outer-element .popover-title { display: none; }`

See the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3404w29/)